# Why does Python 3.4 give the wrong answer for division of large numbers, and how can I test for divisibility?

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, division

In my program, I'm using division to test if the result is an integer, I'm testing divisibility. However, I'm getting wrong answers. Here is an example:

```
print(int(724815896270884803/61))
```

gives 11882227807719424.

```
print(724815896270884803//61)
```

gives the correct result of 11882227807719423.

Why is the floating point result wrong, and how can I test whether the large number is divisible by 61? Do I really need to do integer division and then multiply it back and see if it's equal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The floating-point result is wrong because dividing two ints with `/` produces a float, and the exact result of your division cannot be represented exactly as a `float`. The exact result 11882227807719423 must be rounded to the nearest representable number:

```
In [1]: float(11882227807719423)
Out[1]: 1.1882227807719424e+16
```

Comment: It's not true that both arguments are converted to float before the floating-point division is carried out: instead, Python computes a correctly-rounded division result using integer arithmetic internally (though historically, Python did do something along the lines of converting both ints to a float). The problem here is simply that the division result is not exactly representable as an IEEE 754 binary64  float. (Reference: http://bugs.python.org/issue1811.)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of dividing, you should compute the modulus (`%`):

```
print(724815896270884803 % 61)
```

This is similar to doing an integer division and returning the *remainder* (think back to elementary school long division). A remainder of `0` means it is divisible.

Comment: Oh wow I can't believe I missed that. Duh. I was shortcutting because I wanted to test whether the square root of the division was also an integer, and using `sqrt(724.../61)%1==0`